# I want to differentiate between required and optional text fields in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a React project and I have a problem with the borders of the text fields.

**I want to make the text fields look something like this:**

[image: screen shot of text fields]

In the browser, the borders are looking straight whereas the text fields are rounded.

I tried changing the left of the border but my current result was a bit different.

**My current result:**

[image: screen shot of text field]

```
<TextField
  variant='outlined'
  label='First Name'
  name='first_name'
  id='first_name'
  size='medium'
  placeholder='First Name'
  style={{

      borderLeft: '6px solid #2596be', // Thickened left border
      outlineColor: '#2596be', // Outline color
      ...QuadSignIn.textField, // Your existing styles
  }}
  InputProps={{
      startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position='start'>
              <AccountCircleOutlinedIcon />
          </InputAdornment>
      ),
  }}
  onChange={(e) => {
      handleChange(e);
      formik.handleChange(e);
  }}
  error={
      formik.touched.first_name &&
      Boolean(formik.errors.first_name)
  }
  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
  helperText={
      formik.touched.first_name &&
      Boolean(formik.errors.first_name)
          ? formik.errors.first_name
          : null
  }
  value={signupData.first_name}
/>
```

Comment: Unless you believe the issue is coming from the react code, could you provide the rendered HTML? It will make it easier for us to debug and reproduce the issue. Better still would be to demonstrate the issue with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using the snippet functionality provided.

Comment: @DanielBlack, thank you for the suggestions. I don't think the problem is with my react. I am working with MUI, and I'm making a approach to styling the textfileds in this manner, please find the link: [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP6DG.png). I have attached the textfield that I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a reusable custom field leveraging Formik's useField, and handle the styles based on meta.error (pls see Fomik docs about it). Also you can use the ErrorMessage component given by Formik.